# Two almost identical bits of js, only one working

Tags: javascript, onload, clock

I'm (very) new to javascript, would appreciate someone explaining how I could fix this.

I have two very similar bits of code for a digital clock - difference is that one is an hour ahead of the other. (`var time = h + 1` in one, and `var time = h` in the other)

When I put both on the same page, only one runs.

First bit of code:

```
function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var session = " WST";
    
    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }
    
    
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    
    var time = h + 1 + ":" + m + "" + session;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;
    
    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
    
}

showTime();

</script>
```

Second bit of code:

```
<script>

function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var session = " GMT";
    
    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }
    
    
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    
    var time = h + ":" + m + "" + session;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;
    
    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
    
}

showTime();
</script>
```

The html I use with these is:

```
<div id="MyClockDisplay” class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
```

someone can help me - many thanks in advance.

Comment: "When I put both on the same page, only one runs" what do you mean? They're both on the same page with the same name (`showTime`) and you call `showTime()` once but expect them both to run? Even if they had unique names and called them individually, you're setting the value of the same elements on the page so you'll only see the contents of the second execution.

Comment: Two functions in the same scope can’t share the same name. You are declaring one function and calling it twice.

Answer (score -2):

The code itself works fine. You have to be more specific about "what" does not work.

```js
function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var session = " WST";
    
    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }
    
    
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    
    var time = h + 1 + ":" + m + "" + session;
    console.log(time);
}

function showTime2(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var session = " GMT";
    
    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }
    
    
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    
    var time = h + ":" + m + "" + session;
    console.log(time);
    
}

showTime();
showTime2();
```

Comment: Can’t really say “your code works fine” when you’ve changed it…

Comment: @libik - I appreciate you showing how to change this code to make it work. 

I want to put these clocks onto a Squarespace page. 

Are you able to show me what I need to change my HTML to, please? 

It is currently: `<div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>` 

I know I need to call both showTime and showTime2, but I'm not sure how to. Thank you!